# removeClass() removes the class but jQuery remembering it

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

**In HTML Page**

```
<input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity' />

<div class='submit'>Submit</div>`
```

**In JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
   $('input#quantity').keyup(function()
   {            {
      if($.isNumeric($('input#quantity').val())==true)
      {
    $('.submit').addClass('submit_success');
      }
      else
      {
    $('.submit').removeClass('submit_success');
      }
   });


   $('.submit_success').click(function(e)
   {
      document.write("The DIV is clicked");
   });
});
```

So the idea is when anyone type a numerical value in the `input` box the the `<div class='submit'>` will be added a class 'submit_success' and will look like `<div class='submit submit_success'>`.

**Observations:**

1. Add class 'submit_success' works properly on entering a numerical value.
2. Remove class works properly when a user types alphabet or editing the numerical value with alphabet.
3. Click function executes properly when a user enter numerical data and click on the `<div>`

The problem is occurs when,

STEP 1: User enter a number in the text box. So the add class part is executed.

STEP 2: Now the user delete the number he typed and write an alphabet in the textbox. Now the remove class part executed and the submit_success class is removed.

But still the click function active. When a user click on the `<div>` it writes in the screen "The DIV is clicked". But I guess it should not be executed.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to `on()` instead of `click()` fixes the issue you describe.  Also within the event handler for the `keyup` event `$(this).val()` can be used to retrieve the `input`'s value instead of using the selector.

**Javascript**

```
   $('input#quantity').keyup(function()
   {            
      if($.isNumeric($(this).val())==true) //simplified
      {
        $('.submit').addClass('submit_success');
      }
      else
      {
        $('.submit').removeClass('submit_success');
      }
   });

   $(document).on('click', '.submit_success', function(e)
   {
      alert("The DIV is clicked");
   });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/snYrb/